# OpenCart: Emails are working but wrong from: (CLOSED)

Tags: php, email, opencart

I am using the Mail function in opencart->settings->mail

But when i placed demo order on my site, i am getting email confirmation as below FROM address:

```
<My_Hosting_username@srv21.main-hosting.eu>; on behalf of; Domain <help@domain.com>
```

I tried editing mail.php (system/library/mail.php) as below:

FROM

```
    $header .= 'Date: ' . date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'From: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . '<' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Reply-To: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . '<' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Return-Path: ' . $this->from . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
```

TO

```
    $header .= 'Date: ' . date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') . $this->newline;
    //$header .= 'From: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . '<' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'From: help@domain.com' . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Reply-To: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . '<' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Return-Path: ' . $this->from . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
```

Still i am getting the email like above only.

```
<My_Hosting_username@srv21.main-hosting.eu>; on behalf of; Domain <help@domain.com>
```

Could anybody please help as this discloses hosting information to the customers and creates privacy issues.

Comment: I guess this more for the hosting support and hosting mail-server configuration...

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use mail instead of smtp, as mail is an open relay and allows you to set From as you wish you always get the via. So everything is really ok, if you wish to not have this in your emails you should use SMTP in your setting in admin back-end.

So in short:

Go to System -> settings

Edit your main site

Got to Mail tab

You should specify SMTP  as Mail Protocol

Specify correct data for : SMTP Host, SMTP Username, SMTP Password

And you are done.

Comment: I had also tried that as i am using outlook service for email. the details i entered were: SMTP Host:- smtp.live.com, smtp username: my complete domain email, smtp password, smtp port: 587. But this did not work for me. I was getting error like: AUTH was not accpeted by server.. Could you please help..Thanks

Comment: Well if you get this error it means that either username password combination is wrong, or the server closes the connection on its own, i tried to telnet to smtp.live.com to the specified port and everything worked fine... Do you want to use your own domain for example info@yourdomain.com or user@live.com? Please provide the information so i can guide you further.

Comment: I am using info@yourdomain.com.

Comment: then in your case you should not use live for this purpose, it will always deny authentication. You should have a mail.yourdomain.com subdomain, you should use that, also specify the port it should be 25 , and use the credentials info@yourdomain.com and password.

Comment: I think, still no luck...got two errors--1---...2014-03-25 13:33:17 - PHP Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to mail.mydomain.com:25 (Connection timed out) in /public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 153 ---2nd error-----2014-03-25 13:33:17 - PHP Notice: Error: Connection timed out (110) in /public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 156....But if i enter my domain mail.mydomain.com in URL, it is redirecting me to mail.live.com successfully....mail.mydomain.com is pointing to go.domains.live.com.

Comment: please check your dns records for mail.yourdomain.com and smtp.yourdomain.com the smtp server should not have an open port 80 for you to access online so this was probably your email client record. Firstly identify your smtp server, and afterwards port. If your unable to continue afterwards, please provide your domain, so i can check on my own. And please use mxtoolbox.com to identify correctly your host and ports.

Comment: Try SMTP host: 53431d25f5654a8d7ff394bad97da4.pamx1.hotmail.com   SMTP port:25, smtp username, and smtp password

Comment: same error logs....2014-03-26 4:02:14 - PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to 53431d25f5654a8d7ff394bad97da4.pamx1.hotmail.com:25 (Connection timed out) in public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 153.........
2014-03-26 4:02:14 - PHP Notice:  Error: Connection timed out (110) in public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 156....:-(

Comment: after some more research i noticed you used godaddy, and the only sub-domain i was able to connect via smtp was smtp.yourdomain.com please try this domain with port 25 (that is the only one open), if this does not work also i do not know how to help you further.

Comment: smtp.mydomain.com points to secureserver.net...still both same errors as above. :-(

Comment: secureserver.net is godaddys default handler of emails. You can lookup the server your email is associated to by logging into your godaddy account, launching the email service, click on "Domains" in the left nav, the click on server addresses in the horizontal nav.  What data do you get there?

Comment: i could not find what you are trying to say..as i already told you that i am using outlook email with my domain with above mx record...the outlook server is bay0-pamc2-f.bay0.hotmail.com. i also tried this putting in smtp host with 25 port...still didnt work

Comment: it does not matter what you use it with, you bought a domain in godaddy, thus your email records are orriginally with godaddy email servers (secureserver.net), you may as well change them to use with every other provider, but that does not mean you can not use them with godaddy. They different matters. Go to  https://wcc.secureserver.net/email after you login in the upper menu specify tools->server and there select your domain you will get the smtpout server in my case it was smtpout.europe.secureserver.net

Comment: its Smtpout.secureserver.net

Comment: Yes...but no luck....either i am getting very cheeky or is this the real problem...i am just unable to locate

Comment: if you want the via off you should not use mail as a protocol, smtp is the only other alternative that i am aware of, this is the only certain information. I do not know mate. One last thing to try is browse the same url as before, hover the email adress you need, click 'email setup center' and use the data you will get there for smtp host, smtp port, username, password

Comment: i got something...could you please look...i tried smtpout.secureserver.net and port 80 instead of 25...Now Error is password is wrong...But i am sure password is right...could u advise on this....as now connectivity part is resolved.

Comment: where are you trying this connection? port 80 is for http, 25, 587 are for email transfer, there is not a single possibility that port 80 is correct...

Comment: Thanks for your support. i gave up on this. :-(

Comment: sorry to hear that, yo should never give up :), the solution is somewhere there, it may be as simple as a smtp host change. But its your decision to make.

Comment: But i do not understand, how does it connect with port 80 and host as smtpout.secureserver.net? It should not. Also the php errors gone away with this change..any role of hosting here...do u think..???

Comment: how are you trying to connect? If you are trying in a browser specifying the port you can never access smtp... so we should start here, also i do not know how come you have the host specified as smtpout.secureserver.net, since normally godaddy has this separated by regions meaning if your host is in Asia you should have smtpout.asia.secureserver.net, in Europe smtpout.europe.secureserver.net, normally you should have one specified like this...

Comment: I have tried by same method by putting in smtp host in opencart. 1 more updated: i called godaddy as well, they said i need to use relay-host to use this...i am unaware of this totally.

Comment: yea that is what smtpout servers are for, they are relay servers. I keep thinking that you not checking your data correctly your smtpout server should be like this smtpout.europe.secureserver.net...

Comment: I checked the same in my DNS settings. As u told to me with the URL, i visited and did the same but find nothing..its just saying create a new email account. as i am using godaddy email service

Comment: Don't you have any email accounts listed there? Then do you have an email client connecting to your account, or do you access all your emails via web interface?

Comment: i have pointing my domain's MX to outlook..so using outlook.com email service for my email@mydomain.com

Comment: that's a different matter you may use whichever email service that you  desire and have access to. When you go to https://wcc.secureserver.net/email do you see any email accounts listed there?

Comment: No Jonid. No accounts there.

Comment: Could you try and create an email account there information@yourdomain.com (and connect with that email address) as it seems that the main problem is either outlook does not act as a relay server or you are not connecting via TLS, but i do not know how to check the second part.

Comment: 0 smtp.secureserver.net and
10 mailstore1.secureserver.net and cname: SMTP smtpout.secureserver.net

Comment: did you create the account? In the email settings you got this SMTP smtpout.secureserver.net? if so please try with this account to authendicate in this smtp host

Comment: @shadyyx and Jonid :Thanks a lot for your continous support in this thread. As this effort is not going to a substantial result,so i am bound to close this thread. I once again appreciate Jonid and shaddyx for supporting in this thread.